# Add px or vh value in a javascript's variable

Tags: javascript

I have to insert a value in px or vh in my javascript variable.
I need that var x = 722; become 722px or 100vh.

Thanks

```
var x = 722;

$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= x) {
        $(".B2a").addClass("AI");
        $(".B1a").removeClass("AI");
    }
});
```

Comment: You want `x = x + "px"`?

Comment: Where you want to append those "px" or "vh" in your code?

Comment: As per the documentation https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ `scrollTop` method returns number which is same as pixel. Your current code is correct. Comparing number with a string is not correct.

Comment: I need to set value x = 100vh becouse I need to trigger my script after scrolling the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll variable is already a number, you don't need to add 'px'

You could use `console.log(scroll);` in your function to debug it if necessary !

Answer (score 0):

string stitching a short version:

```js
var a = 'appels';
var b = 3;
var c = b+' '+a;
alert(c);

a = ' I ate';
c += a;
alert(c);
```